# Java repaint() not working

Tags: java, swing, repaint

I am making a simple program to paint a graph and some points in it. The points should be made with methods while changing coordinates of the `g.fillOval` but actually its painting only the last point.

**Here is the code:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class PointGraphWriter extends JPanel
{
   JFrame korniza = new JFrame();
   private int x;
   private int y;
   private int length;
   private String OX;
   private String OY;
   private String emri;
   private int y_height;
   private int x_num;

   public PointGraphWriter()
   {
      int width= 500;
      korniza.setSize(width,width);
      korniza.setVisible(true);
      korniza.setTitle(emri);
      korniza.getContentPane().add(this);

   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {
      g.drawLine(x,y,x+length,y);
      g.drawLine(x,y,x,y-length);
      g.drawString(OX,x+length, y+15);
      g.drawString(OY,x-15,y-length);
      g.drawString("0", x -15,y);
      g.drawString("0", x,y+15);
      g.fillOval(x_num,y-y_height-2, 4 ,4);
   }

   public void setTitle(String name)
   {
      emri= name;
      this.repaint();
   }

   public void setAxes(int x_pos, int y_pos, int axis_length, String x_label, String y_label)
   {
      x= x_pos;
      y=y_pos;
      length= axis_length;
      OX = x_label;
      OY = y_label;   
   }

   public void setPoint1(int height)
   {
      y_height=height;
      x_num = x-2;
      this.repaint();
   }

   public void setPoint2(int height)
   {
      y_height=height;
      x_num = x + length/5-2;
      this.repaint();
   }   
}
```

**and here is the main method:**

```
public class TestPlot
{
   public static void main(String[] a)
   { 
      PointGraphWriter e = new PointGraphWriter();
      e.setTitle("Graph of y = x*x");
      e.setAxes(50, 110, 90, "5", "30");
      int scale_factor = 3;
      e.setPoint1(0 * scale_factor); 
      e.setPoint2(1 * scale_factor);
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to save the __Co-ordinates__ in some `Collections` and iterate on that `Collection` to draw all points each time(a new point is added to the previous list)

Comment: Ehm I'm actually a beginner don't really know how to do that. I just have this exercise as a project in my school.
http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/8932/9n1b.png
      this is the exercise. at the moment i used only setPoint1 and setPoint 2 but i cant fix that problem.

Comment: You can have a look at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11062249/1057230). I am afraid, I cann't do your homework for you. Though a small example will be coming soon..., if the idea is still unclear to you :-)

Comment: yeah i just thought i could use just the repaint() to do the job on there, but it seems like its not working. thanks anyway

Comment: Swing components can't be used from any other thread that the event dispatch thread. Wrap the code of the main method inside a SwingUtilities.invokeLater() call, and everything will go fine. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at this example. Something in lines of this, you might have to incorporate in your example, to make it work. Simply use a `Collection` to store what you have previously painted, and when the new thingy comes along, simply add that thingy to the list, and repaint the whole `Collection` again. As shown below :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RectangleExample {

    private DrawingBoard customPanel;
    private JButton button;

    private Random random;

    private java.util.List<Rectangle2D.Double> rectangles;

    private ActionListener buttonActions = 
                        new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            Rectangle2D.Double rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(
                        (double) random.nextInt(100), (double) random.nextInt(100),
                        (double) random.nextInt(100), (double) random.nextInt(100));
            rectangles.add(rectangle);
            customPanel.setValues(rectangles);
        }
    };

    public RectangleExample() {
        rectangles = new ArrayList<Rectangle2D.Double>();
        random = new Random();
    }   

    private void displayGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rectangle Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));

        customPanel = new DrawingBoard();
        contentPane.add(customPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        button = new JButton("Create Rectangle");
        button.addActionListener(buttonActions);
        contentPane.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new RectangleExample().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}

class DrawingBoard extends JPanel {

    private java.util.List<Rectangle2D.Double> rectangles = 
                                new ArrayList<Rectangle2D.Double>();

    public DrawingBoard() {
        setOpaque(true);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void setValues(java.util.List<Rectangle2D.Double> rectangles) {
        this.rectangles = rectangles;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return (new Dimension(300, 300));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (Rectangle2D.Double rectangle : rectangles) {
            g.drawRect((int)rectangle.getX(), (int)rectangle.getY(),
                    (int)rectangle.getWidth(), (int)rectangle.getHeight());
        }
        System.out.println("WORKING");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for examples of the two common ways to do painting:

1. Keep a List of the objects to be painted
2. Paint onto a BufferedImage

The approach you choose will depend on your exact requirement.